# T4 Template for Mvc using Reflections

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, t4, system.reflection, t4-toolbox

hey i am new to creating T4 Templates for MVC 4. i am stuck with this part of the code.
i have a custom class and i want to get the properties of a different class. Eg:

class name is WOM
and the properties that i want to retrieve is from another class named WOM_JSON.
both belong to the same Namespace and same project. i have also added the assembly reference of the project. but when i use

```
 <# Type e = Type.GetType("Web.Model.WOM");#>
 <#=e.Name#>
```

i get Null reference exception. when i try to generate the code using this template. is there anything that i am missing.? someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

The T4 engine is not aware of your namespace if you don't explicitly import it (at the top of the .tt file)

```
<#@ import namespace="Web.Model" #>
```